# Parsing through a yaml using python

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, dictionary, yaml

I'm trying to make a tuple of 2 keys by reading a yaml.

structure looks like

```
abc:
 xyz:
  efg:
   fgh:
     a: b
  rty:
   ccc:
    - a_table: t0
      b_table: t1

zzz:
 xyz:
  efg:
   fgh:
     a: b
  rty:
   ccc:
    - a_table: t2
      b_table: t3
eee:
 xyz:
  efg:
   fgh:
     a: b
  rty:
   ccc:
    - a_table: t5
      b_table: t6
fff:
 xyz:
  efg:
   fgh:
     a: b
  rty:
   ccc:
    - a_table: t9
      b_table: t10
```

There are multiple entries within the yaml and structure always remain same. I want t0 and t1 to be grouped so that I know they part of one config in yaml. Sometime I may only get **a_table** and sometimes both.

What I have tried already:
I have tried creating a generator to get the list of a_table and b_table separately but I'm unable to map both of them as they their lengths aren't same.

```
def list_convert(document):

   return list(key_find(document))


def key_find(document):

  if isinstance(document, dict):
    for k, v in iteritems(document):
        if k == 'a_table':
             yield v
        elif k == 'b_table':
            yield v

        if isinstance(v, dict):
            for result in key_find(v):
                yield result
        elif isinstance(v, list):
            for d in v:
                for result in key_find(d):
                    yield result
```

How can I achieve this ?

So I have added 4 configs and they all have occurence of a_table and b_table.

Present output I'm getting is

```
Present O/P -('t0', 't1', 't2', 't3', 't5', 't6', 't9', 't10')
Expected O/P - ('t0', 't1'),('t2', 't3'),('t5', 't6'),('t9', 't10')
```

Comment: Updated question with detailed info as suggested

Comment: Updated answer. BTW I would have expected configs with different number of `X_table` in your example.

Comment: Genius! Thank you so much for such a quick reply. This is what I was missing and couldn't make up the logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not bother with a generator, if you do you would need to yield some special token,
that indicates that the following token(s) constitute a new "config".

I suggest you pass in an empty list as second
parameter to your recursively called function and append to that list when you find
a config. Just make sure you pass the list when you recurse as well:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
abc:
 xyz:
  efg:
   fgh:
     a: b
  rty:
   ccc:
    - a_table: t0
      b_table: t1

zzz:
 xyz:
  efg:
   fgh:
     a: b
  rty:
   ccc:
    - b_table: t3
eee:
 xyz:
  efg:
   fgh:
     a: b
  rty:
   ccc:
    - a_table: t5
fff:
 xyz:
  efg:
   fgh:
     a: b
  rty:
   ccc:
    - a_table: t9
      b_table: t10
"""


def build_list(d, res):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        config = []
        for k in d:
            if k == 'a_table':
                config.append(d[k])
            elif k == 'b_table':
               config.append(d[k])
            else:
                build_list(d[k], res)
        if config:   # only filled if a ?_table key was found
            res.append(tuple(config))
    elif isinstance(d, list):
        for item in d:
            build_list(item, res)



def get_table_entries_as_tuple(d):
    res = []
    build_list(d, res)
    return tuple(res)


yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()

res = get_table_entries_as_tuple(yaml.load(yaml_str))
print(type(res), res)
```

which gives:

```
<class 'tuple'> (('t0', 't1'), ('t3',), ('t5',), ('t9', 't10'))
```

Please note that I slightly changed your input, to make sure partial configurations work as well.